# PHP/Wordpress Error Reporting Won't Turn On

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm writing PHP scripts where I include `wp-load.php`. Whenever there's an error in my PHP code, I only get a 500 error and no output. I added to my `wp-config.php` (And my script file):

```
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
```

but still not getting any error messages. These are not web server misconfigurations. They are always just PHP errors. No error.log either.

Comment: See https://digwp.com/2009/07/monitor-php-errors-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Change parameter "`WP_DEBUG`" in wp-config.php file. set parameter to `true`.

> define('WP_DEBUG', true);

Comment: Also
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true ); and
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true ); for the log file